# Increment or decrement numbers while <C-a> and C-x> bindings are unmapped in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I keep the increment/decrement bindings `<C-a>` and `<C-x>` unmapped in my vimrc, because I rarely need them and they can cause a lot of headache if unknowingly pressed during development.

For the rare case where I do need this functionality, is there a way I can invoke the increment/decrement actions without temporarily binding them again?

Comment: @ggorlen - you are right. I mistakenly assumed `<C-x>` could work on a block of code, but it only operates on the first number of each line. I will update my question to simplify.

Comment: OK, then community robot voted to close but it was a bad closure because you removed that part of the question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Well, if you know how to disable those commands, you certainly know how to enable them, right? Besides, you can use `:normal! <C-a>` or `<C-v><C-a>`.

Comment: Yeah, just looking for a solution that doesn't rely on states. `:normal! <C-a>` and `<C-v><C-a>` don't seem to work for me while `<C-a>` is remapped. Care to post an answer with more details?

Comment: Oh I saw the full command from the other comment below: `exe "normal! \<C-A>"` works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings that have been remapped or unmapped can still be executed via the following ex command form:

```
:exe "normal! [binding]"
```

So to answer my original question, I can execute `<C-a>` or `<C-x>` while they are unmapped using the following ex commands:

```
# Increment
:exe "normal! \<C-A>"

# Decrement
:exe "normal! \<C-X>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can "completely" avoid temporarily binding them again, however you could write a function in your config to locally bind, increment, and locally unbind. Something like

```
function! g:Increment()
    nnoremap <buffer> <C-a> <C-a>
    exe "normal \<C-a>"
    :nunmap <buffer> <C-a>
endfunction
```

and the analog for Decrement.

You could then position the cursor over the value you want to increment and run `:call Increment()`.

Comment: Just use `:normal!` instead, it doesn't expand mappings. Simply `exe "normal! \<C-a>"` will work, without having to restore the mappings.